# groupby not behaving as expected

Tags: scala

The below code is suppose to sum the values of a list of tuples but when two or more tuples contain the same value , the tuple is just outputted once :

```
var data = List((1, "1") , (1, "one"))            //> data  : List[(Int, java.lang.String)] = List((1,1), (1,one))

        data = data.groupBy(_._2).map {
            case (label, vals) => (vals.map(_._1).sum, label)
        }.toList.sortBy(_._1).reverse

println(data)                                     //> List((1,1))
```

The output of above is `List((1,1))` when I'm expecting `List((1,1) , (1,"one"))`

Does the groupBy function paramaters need to be tweaked to fix this ?

Comment: How are you expecting to get `(1,"two")`? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: This link may be useful: [scalapuzzlers N6](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-006)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it does behave as expected. `groupBy` returns a map. When you `map` over a map, you construct a new map, where, of course, each key is unique. Here, you'd have the key `1` twice…

You should then call `toList` before calling `map`, not after.